# How to implement a WinUI 3 UserControl with ComboBox, Enum and DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, winui-3

Suppose we have

```
public enum MyEnum {None, First, Second}
```

and in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, we have

```
private IList<MyEnum> _myEnums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToList();
public IList<MyEnum> MyEnums => _myEnums;

public MyEnum SelectedMyEnum {get;set;}
```

and in `MainWindow.xaml` we have

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyEnums}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedMyEnum, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This works, as expected.

Now suppose we want to replace `ComboBox` with a user control, i.e.

```
<local:ExampleControl MyEnums="{x:Bind MyEnums}" SelectedMyEnum="{x:Bind SelectedMyEnum, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So, in `ExampleControl.xaml` we have

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox 
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyEnums}"
      SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedMyEnum,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and in `ExampleControl.xaml.cs` we have

```
// SelectedMyEnum

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMyEnumProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedMyEnum",
        typeof(MyEnum),
        typeof(ExampleControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(MyEnum.None));  // (1)

public MyEnum SelectedMyEnum
{
    get { return (MyEnum)GetValue(SelectedMyEnumProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedMyEnumProperty, value); } // (2)
}

// MyEnums

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyEnumsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyEnums",
        typeof(IEnumerable<MyEnum>),
        typeof(ExampleControl), null
        );
public IEnumerable<MyEnum> MyEnums
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<MyEnum>)GetValue(MyEnumsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyEnumsProperty, value); }
}
```

But this doesn't work. On startup, the `SelectedMyEnum` setter (2) is called repeatedly with the value `MyEnum.None` until there is a stack overflow,

```
System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Instead of `new PropertyMetadata(MyEnum.None)` in (1), I tried

```
new PropertyMetadata(MyEnum.None, OnEnumChanged)
```

with

```
private static void OnEnumChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) 
{
    var control = (ExampleControl)obj;
    MyEnum myVal = (MyEnum)args.NewValue;
}
```

but that made no difference, the function `OnEnumChanged` was called repeatedly, along with the setter, with `myVal == MyEnum.None`, until stack overflow.

I checked the [WinUI Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery) for examples of dependency properties for enums, but couldn't find any, but there were plenty of examples for double, int, and bool, e.g. [ItemHeight in WrapPanel](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/Common/WrapPanel.cs), I think I'm doing this right.

I must be missing something, but can't see it. I've searched on `ComboBox`, `DependencyProperty`, `Enum`, and found some matches, e.g [Enum as a DependencyProperty of a UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567874/enum-as-a-dependencyproperty-of-a-usercontrol.html), but I didn't find them helpful. Any help is appreciated.

Environment:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.0+32210.238
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161
```

Comment: You don't show the most important part, how you set the data context of your control. You also don't show the second most important part, the actual stack trace you claim overflows, because the code as shown here isn't going to overflow. You wrote something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @Blindy, it's a minimalized example, the x:Bind's in the .xaml file are binding directly to properties in the associated .xaml.cs files.  I'll include the error message I observe in debugging in the question, but it's basically  System.StackOverflowException
and StackTrace: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace. Apart from using statements and boilerplate, there is no other code.

Comment: @Blindy, also, if I change MyEnum to string in the control, and bind to an array of strings for the items source and a string for the selected item, everything works as expected, with no other changes. I can obviously work around this, but I would like to understand what's going on with enum and dependency properties, that's my preferred implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/860828/winui-3-usercontrol-with-combobox-dependencyproper.html) by Roy Li - MSFT on the Microsoft Q&A site. It's related to a WinUI defect in the `x:Bind` markup extension. In the user control, in the case of `enums`, `x:Bind` doesn't work with `SelectedMyEnum`, it needs to be written using `Binding` as

```
<ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyEnums}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyEnum,Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

and `DataContext` set to `this`. In my experiments, it appears to be only an issue with `x:Bind` and `TwoWay` binding, `OneWay` and `OneTime` bindings with `x:Bind` appear okay. And not an issue if binding to strings rather than enums.